# .json - File in Pandas-DataFrame: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with some result-files of a study which are saved in a .json-format.
However, I could work with some of them in Python-Pandas using tutorials and going like:

```
file = open(path, 'r')
    meta_df = pd.read_json(file)
```

Using the same method for another .json yields:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

The .json looks like:

```
[
{
"reference": null,
"enter_app": 1603456818731,
"dummy1": 1603456925901,
"dummy2": 1603456971867,
"start_time": 1603456828542,
"end_time": null,
"entered_link": null,
"start_task": null,
"end_task": null,
"start_task2": null,
"end_task2": null,
"End_begin": null,
"End_end": null
 },
{
"test_version": "7",
"component_id": "10",
"ResultId": "2222",
"Id": "2",
"device": "desktop",
"operatingSystem": "Linux OS",
"link": "00000000",
"browser": "BrowserName = Chrome\nVersion = 80.0.3987.163",
"language": "de",
"age": null,
"gender": null
},
{
"baseline": {
  "1": 33,
  "2": 19,
  "3": 36,
  "4": 4
 },
"intermediate": {
  "1": null,
  "2": null,
  "3": null,
  "4": null
 },
"post": {
  "1": null,
  "2": null,
  "3": null,
  "4": null
 }
},
{
"begin_p": null,
"end_p": null
}
]
```

Do you have any idea?
Seems to have to do with the structure of the .json, right? But as it is saved like this for all participants, I would like to

Comment: `The .json looks like:` like what?

Comment: sorry: had some issues with the code cell

Comment: your code works for me, maybe you do something with the file before sending it to pd? json parse it, iterate threw it?

Comment: you're right. It works with this example. I went through a list of more examples but the older ones had an issue with another "null" : e.g. ..."End_end": null
 }, NULL,
{
"test_version": "7", ...